# Database model has no attribute

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is a Many-to-Many db with Flask_sqlalchemy. I believe I have followed the examples precisely but I get `AttributeError: 'Song' object has no attribute 'category'` when running this and I can't figure out what's wrong.

How can I fix this?

```
association_table = db.Table('association',
                             db.Column('songs_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('songs.id')),
                             db.Column('genres_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('genres.id'))
                             )

class Song(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'songs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    artist = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=False,
                       unique=False, nullable=False)
    added = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    genres = db.relationship("Genre", secondary=association_table, backref=db.backref('songs'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)

class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True,
                         unique=True, nullable=False)
```

My insert looks like this:

```
    song = Song(title="test title", artist="test name")
    genre = Genre(category="test category")
    song.category.append(genre)
    db.session.add(song)
    db.session.commit()
```

EDIT:
I also have issues with querying.

```
test = Genre.query.filter(Genre.songs.any(title="that song")).all()
print(test)
```

prints `[<Genre 3>, <Genre 4>, <Genre 5>]` instead of the genres. Why is this?

Comment: You're printing the queryset of class instances, so you can access the names of your genres with **[genre.category for genre in test]** or provide the genre class with a __repr__ function as you did with the _song_ class.

Comment: Such a small correction but it works now, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Song` class has no attribute by the name of category, yet you're attempting to append your genre to it.
Did you mean to do this?

```
song = Song(title="test title", artist="test name")
genre = Genre(category="test category")
song.genres.append(genre)   # You wrote category, but your class only has a "genres" relationship
db.session.add(song)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed one of my issues. I added one more question because it's the stil the same code and I thought this would be easier than creating a new page.

Comment: @user15705608 As these are different questions, your edit doesn't provide details for the original question and should thus be a "new" question. Otherwise a new answer could be confusing for future visitors when answers relate to different questions.

Comment: Good point, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.